# Unit of Work with StructureMap 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, structuremap

I'm new with using structuremap and I'm not sure if I configured `IoC.cs` properly.
I have an ASP.Net Project and used `Unit Of Work`. this is how my `IoC.cs` file looks like:

**IoC.cs**

```
namespace Portal.Web.DependencyResolution {
    using Portal.Data.Context;
    using Portal.Service;
    using Portal.Service.Interface;
    using StructureMap;
    using StructureMap.Pipeline;

    public static class IoC {
        public static IContainer Initialize() {
            return new Container(c => { 
                c.AddRegistry<DefaultRegistry>();
                c.For<IUnitOfWork>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.Singleton).Use<PortalDbContext>();
                c.For<IAccount>().Use<AccountService>();
                c.For<IStandard>().Use<StandardService>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

with this configuration this error occures some times

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.
```

I already have read many other SO questions with same topic as error above and they all suggest to use `.toList()` and enumerate but I guess that is not my problem.

so for summarize I'd like to use `Unit Of Work` + `Structure Map 3 DI` in `ASP MVC5`, how I configure my `IoC.cs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very bad idea to use singleton for dbcontext in web application.
You should consider to change this to PerHttpRequest lifecycle (if it exists in structuremap) or PerResolve lifecycle:

Per HttpRequest:

```
For<IUnitOfWork>().LifecycleIs(new HttpContextLifecycle()).Use<PortalDbContext>();
```

**Update:**
*in this case, you **should not** use your IUnitOfWork in using statement and lay responsibility of disposing it on your DI container.*

Per Resolve:

```
For<IUnitOfWork>().Use<PortalDbContext>();
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm asking, I don't know which and how should I configure my DbContext. I've read http://structuremap.github.io/object-lifecycle/supported-lifecycles/ StructureMap 3 documentation but I'm still confused

Comment: after a day of testing it turned out I still have the problem even when I used `For<IUnitOfWork>().LifecycleIs(new HttpContextLifecycle()).Use<PortalDbContext>();` 
Though error changed to `System.InvalidOperationException: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.`

Comment: Did you use db context in using statement?

Comment: ok forgive me, I found out and solved my new problem `System.InvalidOperationException: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.` that was because I did not used `.toList()` somewhere.